# Python encrypt data through sockets

Tags: python, sockets, openssl, cryptography, rsa

I'm currently developing a Python app divided in two scripts, which will be put each in one Docker container.

One imitates the work of an automate by creating randomly generated data that I store in a dict object then sends it to the other script via the python `socket` library.

The data I send is presented like this:

```
{
  "unit": 1,
  "timestamp": 1561566549688,
  "params": {
    "0": {
      "temp_tank": 3.2,
      "temp_ext": 11.7,
      "tank_weight": 3686,
      "finished_product_weight": 406,
      "pH_rate": 7.2,
      "potassium_rate": 36,
      "NaCL_concentration": 1.7,
      "salmonella_level": 18,
      "e-coli_level": 40,
      "listeria_level": 30
    },
    "1": {
      "temp_tank": 3.6,
      "temp_ext": 10.2,
      "tank_weight": 4597,
      "finished_product_weight": -219,
      "pH_rate": 7.0,
      "potassium_rate": 44,
      "NaCL_concentration": 1.4,
      "salmonella_level": 29,
      "e-coli_level": 41,
      "listeria_level": 39
    },
    "2": {
      "temp_tank": 3.6,
      "temp_ext": 11.7,
      "tank_weight": 4587,
      "finished_product_weight": -938,
      "pH_rate": 6.9,
      "potassium_rate": 39,
      "NaCL_concentration": 1.1,
      "salmonella_level": 35,
      "e-coli_level": 42,
      "listeria_level": 50
    },
    "3": {
      "temp_tank": 3.3,
      "temp_ext": 10.3,
      "tank_weight": 4120,
      "finished_product_weight": -38,
      "pH_rate": 7.2,
      "potassium_rate": 41,
      "NaCL_concentration": 1.7,
      "salmonella_level": 32,
      "e-coli_level": 38,
      "listeria_level": 41
    },
    "4": {
      "temp_tank": 2.5,
      "temp_ext": 12.5,
      "tank_weight": 3723,
      "finished_product_weight": -134,
      "pH_rate": 7.1,
      "potassium_rate": 43,
      "NaCL_concentration": 1.3,
      "salmonella_level": 22,
      "e-coli_level": 39,
      "listeria_level": 30
    },
    "5": {
      "temp_tank": 3.2,
      "temp_ext": 9.5,
      "tank_weight": 4236,
      "finished_product_weight": 116,
      "pH_rate": 7.2,
      "potassium_rate": 41,
      "NaCL_concentration": 1.4,
      "salmonella_level": 19,
      "e-coli_level": 39,
      "listeria_level": 44
    },
    "6": {
      "temp_tank": 2.8,
      "temp_ext": 11.6,
      "tank_weight": 4279,
      "finished_product_weight": -616,
      "pH_rate": 6.9,
      "potassium_rate": 46,
      "NaCL_concentration": 1.2,
      "salmonella_level": 29,
      "e-coli_level": 47,
      "listeria_level": 47
    },
    "7": {
      "temp_tank": 2.8,
      "temp_ext": 13.0,
      "tank_weight": 3774,
      "finished_product_weight": 290,
      "pH_rate": 7.1,
      "potassium_rate": 38,
      "NaCL_concentration": 1.6,
      "salmonella_level": 20,
      "e-coli_level": 41,
      "listeria_level": 39
    },
    "8": {
      "temp_tank": 3.6,
      "temp_ext": 13.0,
      "tank_weight": 3978,
      "finished_product_weight": 381,
      "pH_rate": 6.8,
      "potassium_rate": 45,
      "NaCL_concentration": 1.4,
      "salmonella_level": 35,
      "e-coli_level": 37,
      "listeria_level": 49
    },
    "9": {
      "temp_tank": 2.9,
      "temp_ext": 10.2,
      "tank_weight": 4109,
      "finished_product_weight": -174,
      "pH_rate": 7.1,
      "potassium_rate": 46,
      "NaCL_concentration": 1.5,
      "salmonella_level": 24,
      "e-coli_level": 36,
      "listeria_level": 45
    }
  }
}
```

The second script retrieves that data with the same `socket` library, and then pushes it into a remote database.

This part works without any issue, I can easily send the json formatted string of the data dictionary from the generation script to the other one, with sockets.

The problem I have now is that I want to make the socket connection secured, by asymmetrically encrypting and decrypting the json formatted string.

For that I use the `cryptography` python library and encrypt using RSA.

When I start the scripts, when getting to the "socket send" line, both scripts crash. The first outputs this error:

> *cryptography.exceptions.InternalError: Unknown OpenSSL error. This error is commonly encountered when another library is not cleaning up the OpenSSL error stack. If you are using cryptography with another library that us
>   es OpenSSL try disabling it before reporting a bug. Otherwise please file an issue at https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues with information on how to reproduce this. ([])*

And the second outputs this:

> *ValueError: Ciphertext length must be equal to key size.*

I don't seem to have any other running library using OpenSSL.

Here are my two scripts:

**generate.py**

```py
##
#   Generate file containing data from automates
##

import sys
import random
import json
import glob
import os
import time
import socket
import threading

from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding


# Generate the private and public keys once

# from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
# private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
#     public_exponent=65537,
#     key_size=20480,
#     backend=default_backend()
# )
# public_key = private_key.public_key()
#
# pem = private_key.private_bytes(
#     encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
#     format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
#     encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
# )
#
# with open('private.pem', 'wb') as f:
#     f.write(pem)
#
# pem = public_key.public_bytes(
#     encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
#     format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
# )
#
# with open('public.pem', 'wb') as f:
#     f.write(pem)

with open("public.pem", "rb") as key_file:
    public_key = serialization.load_pem_public_key(
        key_file.read(),
        backend=default_backend()
    )


# Handle argument related errors, we only want 2! No more no less.
if len(sys.argv) > 3:
    print("Please give max 2 arguments.")
    exit()
elif len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Please give the amount of time for the update cycle (in seconds), and the unit number.")
    exit()
else:
    print("Initializing...")

# Registering the passed arguments
cycle_value = float(sys.argv[1])
unit_number = int(sys.argv[2])


def encrypt_data(data):
    return bytes(base64.b64encode(public_key.encrypt(
        data,
        padding.OAEP(
            mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
            algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
            label=None
        )
    )), 'utf-8')


# Get the tank weight of the previous data set
def get_last_tank_weight(id):
    if not os.path.isdir('generated-data'):
        os.mkdir('generated-data')
    if len(glob.glob('generated-data/*.json')) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        list_of_files = glob.glob('generated-data/*.json')
        latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)

        return int(json.loads(open(latest_file, 'r').read())["params"][str(id - 1)]["tank_weight"])


# Generate random value for each automate
def generate_values(id):
    tank_weight = int(round(random.uniform(3512, 4607), 0))

    params = {
        "temp_tank": round(random.uniform(2.5, 4), 1),
        "temp_ext": round(random.uniform(8, 14), 1),
        "tank_weight": tank_weight,
        "finished_product_weight": get_last_tank_weight(id) - tank_weight,
        "pH_rate": round(random.uniform(6.8, 7.2), 1),
        "potassium_rate": int(round(random.uniform(35, 47), 0)),
        "NaCL_concentration": round(random.uniform(1.0, 1.7), 1),
        "salmonella_level": int(round(random.uniform(17, 37), 0)),
        "e-coli_level": int(round(random.uniform(35, 49), 0)),
        "listeria_level": int(round(random.uniform(28, 54), 0))
    }

    return params


# Create and fill the json data file for the unit
def fill_json():
    timestamp = int(time.time() * 1000)

    json_output = {
        "unit": unit_number,
        "timestamp": timestamp,
        "params": {}
    }

    params = {}
    f_automates = open("automates.json", "r")
    json_automates = json.loads(f_automates.read())[str(unit_number)]

    print("Generating values...")
    for automate in json_automates:
        params[int(automate["num"]) - 1] = generate_values(automate["num"])

    json_output["params"] = params

    filename = "paramunite_" + str(unit_number) + "_" + str(timestamp) + ".json"

    with open("generated-data/" + filename, "w+") as json_file:
        json.dump(json_output, json_file)

    print("file " + filename + " successfully created.")

    print(encrypt_data(bytes(json.dumps(json_output), 'utf-8')))

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 25565))
        # s.connect(('pyconcentrator', 25565))

        s.sendall(encrypt_data(bytes(json.dumps(json_output), 'utf-8')))

    # Line to make script wait for new creation
    threading.Timer(cycle_value, fill_json).start()


# Launch main script!
fill_json()
```

**concentrator.py**

```py
import socket
import json
import base64
import mysql.connector as mariadb

from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding


host = socket.gethostname()
port = 25565

s = socket.socket()
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(60)

with open("private.pem", "rb") as key_file:
    private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
        key_file.read(),
        password=None,
        backend=default_backend()
    )


def decrypt_data(data):
    return private_key.decrypt(
        data,
        padding.OAEP(
            mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
            algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
            label=None
        )
    )


# Connect to MariaDB
def connect_to_db():
    return mariadb.connect(
        host='mariadbaubeurre', port=3306, user='root', password='beurette', database='beurre'
        # host='127.0.0.1', port=3307, user='root', password='', database='test'
    )


# Get the type of the automate given its id, by searching in the automates.json file
def get_automate_type(id, unit):
    return json.loads(open('automates.json', 'r').read())[str(unit)][int(id)-1]["type"]


def send_to_db(data):
    mariadb_connection = connect_to_db()
    cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()

    i = 1
    # Prepare INSERT SQL query
    sql = "INSERT INTO measures (`measure_datetime`, `measure_temp_cuve`, `measure_temp_ext`, `measure_weight_milk`, `measure_weight_product`, `measure_ph`, `measure_k_plus`, `measure_nacl`, `measure_bacteria_salmonella`, `measure_bacteria_ecoli`, `measure_bacteria_listeria`, `measure_fk_automaton`) VALUES "
    for y in data["params"]:
        sql += "({}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}),".format(
            data["timestamp"],
            data["params"][y]["temp_tank"],
            data["params"][y]["temp_ext"],
            data["params"][y]["tank_weight"],
            data["params"][y]["finished_product_weight"],
            data["params"][y]["pH_rate"],
            data["params"][y]["potassium_rate"],
            data["params"][y]["NaCL_concentration"],
            data["params"][y]["salmonella_level"],
            data["params"][y]["e-coli_level"],
            data["params"][y]["listeria_level"],
            "(SELECT automaton_id FROM automatons WHERE automaton_fk_unit = (SELECT unit_id FROM `units` WHERE unit_fk_site = 1 AND unit_num = {}) AND automaton_type LIKE '{}' AND automaton_num = {})".format(
                data["unit"], get_automate_type(i, data["unit"]), i)
        )
        i += 1

    cursor.execute(sql[:-1] + ";")
    mariadb_connection.commit()
    mariadb_connection.close()


def wait_for_data():
    output = ""

    print("Waiting for connection...")

    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("Receiving from ", addr, "...")
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        output += decrypt_data(data).decode('utf-8')
        if not data:
            break

    print(json.loads(output))
    send_to_db(json.loads(output))
    wait_for_data()


wait_for_data()

s.close()
```

I'm stuck with this, and can't find any way to solve it.
I'm a noob in cryptography, so maybe I do not use the right encryption method or something like that, but I'm a bit lost with all the encryption possibilities.

Thank you!!

Comment: Why not use TLS?

Comment: @user207421 Do you mean simply replacing all the cryptography related code by a TLS socket implementation? I don't know much about SSL/TLS, the only directive I have is to use asymmetric cryptography, would this method fit?

Comment: There are several problems I understand here, and perhaps a few that I don't. The one I don't understand is the recursive calls to `fill_json()` from a separate thread. It's clear that method leaves resources open but the full implications of this design escape me. In the second script, the `recv()` loop assumes that `recv(1024)` always returns 1024 bytes. This is not true, and thus this is bug. And you should be using hybrid crypto anyway, and finally, yes, you should just throw all this away and use TLS.

Comment: I recursively call `fill_json()`because it's a function that needs to be executed every x seconds (the `cycle_value` variable), it maybe not the best way to do it but it does the job for what i need. And yeah I thought of that recv(1024) being an issue, but since I don't know the exact bytes length, I couldn't easily figure it out...
I unfortunately cannot use hybrid crypto, simply because it is a school project and the instructions specify to use asymmetric cryptography..
But yeah thank you both for your fast answers! I will implement TLS right away.

Comment: Asymmetric cryptography is a poor solution, highyl inefficient. It should only be used to establish identity. I suggest a thorough review of the security requirements for this application.